# Missing private key in keychain access

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

Hi I need to export my private key for push notification. So i followed all steps from https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/
But after creating AppId I am not able to see private key (drop down arrow) in my key chain access.
I have read several solution but they were not related to mine.

Here is image to show what I mean :

[image]

Any idea what i have to do now ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you create certificate on other system and transfer these on another?

Comment: I am just downloading certificates from dev portal. @GouravJoshi

Comment: @sharadchauhan  If you have already created your certificates, then check it in your previous system, from there you need to export on your existing system then you will get private key.

Comment: @GouravJoshi okay i will try. But most probably i don't have access to the old system.

Comment: If you don't have access to old system then you have to revoke all and generate new ones, else take a provision to access certificates

Comment: @GouravJoshi I got it. I found it on the system which was probably used for making them. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Thats great....